# MySQL Transaction

Tags: mysql, transactions, client-server

It could be a dumb question, and tried to search for it and found nothing.

I been using mysql for years(not that to long) but i never had tried mysql transactions.
Now my question is, what would happen if i issue an insert or delete statement from multiple clients using transactions? does it would lock the table and prevent other client to perform there query?
what would happen if other client issue a transaction query while the other client still have unfinished transaction?

I appreciate for any help will come.

P.S. most likely i will use insert using a file or csv it could be a big chunk of data or just a small one.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL automatically performs locking for single SQL statements to keep clients from interfering with each other, but this is not always sufficient to guarantee that a database operation achieves its intended result, because some operations are performed over the course of several statements. In this case, different clients might interfere with each other.

Source: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2036581&seqNum=12